# Exception in XML transformation : Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.datapower.com/extensions

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

We are validating XML using XSLT in C# and while doing transformation getting exception "Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.datapower.com/extensions".

**Question**  Is there any extension lib available for the same or any other solution to fix this issue. We have so many such third party dependencies and looking for common solution.

Any pointer/help will be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
        Encoding utf8noBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);   
        XsltArgumentList xsltArguments = null;
        XsltExtension xsltExtension = new XsltExtension();
        xsltArguments = new XsltArgumentList();
        xsltArguments.AddExtensionObject("urn:actl-xslt", xsltExtension);
        xsltArguments.AddExtensionObject("http://exslt.org/dates-and-times", new Mvp.Xml.Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes());

        XPathDocument myXPathDocument = new XPathDocument(sourceDoc);
        XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(resultDoc, null);

        myXslTransform.Load(xsltDoc);

        myXslTransform.Transform(myXPathDocument, xsltArguments, writer);
        writer.Close();
```

**XSL Snap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
date:doc="http://www.exslt.org/date"
extension-element-prefixes="dp date" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dyn regexp date func" version="1.0">
```

Comment: Extensions are usually processor specific so don't expect an extension supported in IBM's DataPower processor to be supported in Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen, I understand that MS doesnot support IBM but my question was, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with the IBM DataPower processor and its extensions, the use of `extension-element-prefixes="dp` in your XSLT suggests that the code uses an extension element in that DataPower prefix, as far as I know, XslCompiledTransform does not allow you to set/add/configure extension elements at all.

Comment: If the DataPower namespace is used for extension functions, then see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/extending-xslt-style-sheets how to do that for XslCompiledTransform, .NET is powerful enough to implement a lot of things outside of XSLT, it depends on what the dp extensions do.

Comment: @MartinHonnen :  XslCompiledTransform does not allow you to set/add/configure extension elements at all : we can add custom extension or DLL reference. Just Like i have added for exslt.  XslCompiledTransform, .NET : is powerful, but we dont have enough time to migrate existing one to .net

Comment: I am talking about "extension elements" in the sense of the XSLT spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#extension-element, that is not something that XslCompiledTransform supports as far as I know and is certainly not done with `xsltArguments.AddExtensionObject` . "Extension functions" are supported, yes, as shown in the link or as partly used in your code.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, it does help us in deciding next step.